# Javascript execution stops in Chrome when Developer Toolbar is open

Tags: google-chrome, web-developer-toolbar

Whenever I'm developing in Chrome, I don't have issues until I try executing scripts while the Chrome Developer Toolbar is open. When it's open, and (for instance), I click on an element with an event tied to it, the toolbar will flip over to the Scripts tab and show what I've attached below.

When I close the toolbar, it seems that the execution of the script picks up and runs the actions I was waiting for.

I should note that there are no errors in my JS and when the toolbar is closed it runs perfectly. There must be something in the Chrome settings that pauses javascript execution while the toolbar is open.

I've disabled all extensions and restarted the browser to no effect.

[image: Chrome Developer Tools]

Comment: Is this in addition to the breakpoint you have set? (If not, right side pane in the debugger, right click in 'breakpoints' & 'clear all'

Comment: I'm honestly not an expert at the front-end stuff, so I'm not even sure how to set a breakpoint. On the toolbar sidebar, under the DOM Breakpoints header, it says "No Breakpoints", so unless I should be looking elsewhere, I think it's something else.

Comment: The maroon arrow is the give away, DOM breakponts are something else, it should be the "Breakpoints" section above

Comment: Ah, it was an event listener breakpoint that was checked. Thanks for the pointer. That fixed it.